# ¿Cómo obtener token de acceso en Api Graph de Facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook-api

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y necesitó usar el api de Facebook ya adelante un paso el cual es obtener un token de la aplicación enviando:
client_id , client_secret, grant_type  a esta url :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

esta solicitud me devuelve algo así:

```
728445345330|ctprcfHOgdfgdfdfgsp2w
```

la cual es un id y un key separados por una barra vertical (|).
Ok hasta aquí todo bien, luego ejecuto una segunda solicitud a esta url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" + appId+"/accounts?access_token=728445345330|ctprcfHOgdfgdfdfgsp2w"
```

y en este caso me devuelve un json:

```
{"data":[{"id":"109757178392825","login_url":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/checkpoint\/test-user-login\/109757178392825\/?is_sandbox=0&sandbox_asset_type=test_user&page_id=0","access_token":"EAAKWexagxaYBACN8DIW77sXL3WzBCJisyXvBCBrcaXJs5GzkYuf8NZCGiPc0PS9oVZAqky0bRNjRl6j7agZApswA2QUU68iN5c5pj5KZC538KGCZBnyDLaZBaUjZC4ZAEB8ST37TJW9DmdgBZAuXFxFg6l2ScnzHF3OBr4ipiGPZBZCIyHUIaJ046GK1YNmPWLr0ZBAMvyB7a3tIWZB0Ve0uojm16"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUjJaZAFc5XzJYSkg2Q2tQUVQzSkpJbHhwMnU1Rlp5QzJRVGRIeEF4Y3BuMVJrM0p3enFpTHg5UHAwd08tWWZAUQ1RqNWRYM1NNR0xaMUpiOUVfUndMZA2V3","after":"QVFIUjJaZAFc5XzJYSkg2Q2tQUVQzSkpJbHhwMnU1Rlp5QzJRVGRIeEF4Y3BuMVJrM0p3enFpTHg5UHAwd08tWWZAUQ1RqNWRYM1NNR0xaMUpiOUVfUndMZA2V3"}}}
```

El problema está que cuando trato de hacer cualquier solicitud con este token la Api me responden con un json que dice lo siguiente:

```
{"id":"109757178392825","name":"Open Graph Test User"}
```

y este es el codigo donde estoy tratando de usar el acces_token:

```
 public async Task<string> TestFIAsync( string access_token)
        {
            var respuesta = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
                var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cfeed";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
            }

            return respuesta;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué exactamente esperas obtener con una petición a `/v13.0/me`? No veo que estés logueando a ningún usuario. Si estás intentando implementar autenticación  con facebook en una web funciona de la siguiente manera. Facebook despues de que el usuario se loguee con el boton `login with facebook` te va a enviar un `access token` al que puedes acceder mediante un callback en `FB.getLoginStatus`. Con ese `access_token` es con el que haces la petición a `https://graph.facebook.com/me` para obtener los datos del usuario logueado después de que él te dé permiso.

Comment: No puedes simplemente pedir los datos de un usuario sin que previamente él te haya dado autorización. Quizá [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2PChWTwmM8) te sea de ayuda.